# Freescale HCS08 Background Debug Module (BDM) connector: clarification wanted

Tags: connector

I'm designing a device which contains a Freescale HCS08 (9S08GT32). In the datasheet I found this drawing (page 237):

[image]

I can't tell from the text whether this is a view on the PCB's header or on the BDM' cable connector. Can you tell me which it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the view looking straight down (top view) on the header pins as they stick out of the board.  The cable on my P&E Micro BDM would plug in from the left, with the red stripe at the top.